# Using Image Stored in Database (image path)

Tags: c#, winforms

I want this button's image use the image stored in database (image path)...

```
        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a = button11.Text;
            string connString = "Server=Localhost;Database=test;Uid=*****;password=*****;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = ("Select link from testtable where ID=" + a);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //button11.Image = ex.ToString();
            }

            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                button11.Image = reader["path"].ToString();                    
            }
        }
```

I think the error lies in `"reader["path"].ToString();"` but I don't know what syntax to use.

Comment: warning your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: What is exactly stored in the `path` column of the database? Is it the path to the image file on the disk?

Comment: yes, the path is the image file in disk.. 

@Daniel A. White .. what do you mean?

Comment: you aren't using a parameterized query.

Comment: i thought this a byte. `:D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored the path to the image file on the disk in the `path` column, you should laod the image:

```
    string path = (string)reader["path"];
    button11.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

Side note: Never pass the values directly from a user input to a database query. It is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Use parameters instead:

```
command.CommandText = "Select link from testtable where ID=@id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(a));
```

Comment: Thanks! i found another error in my code, got to fix it first.. thanks btw.. il be back..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string path = reader.GetString(0);
            button11.Image = Image.FromFile(path);                    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ( Written right to answer box, may be there are typo! )

```
    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = button11.Text;
        string imagePath;
        string connString = "Server=Localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;password=root;";
        using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        using(MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "Select link from testtable where ID=@id";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(a));

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                imagePath= (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            //button11.Image = ex.ToString();
            }

            button11.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        }
    }
```